# LoadError: Expected {app_path}/models/model file.rb to define model name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multithreading

I am getting this error While running this

```
LoadError: Expected /home/user/Desktop/Tripurari/myapp/app/models/host.rb to define Host##
```

But every thing on it's place. Can some one tell me what the exact problem is below method.

```
def self.check_all(keyword)
  memo_mutex = Mutex.new
  memo       = {}
  threads    = []
  name       = keyword.keyword
  SITES.each do |site_and_options|
    threads << Thread.new do
      @host = Host.find_or_create_by_name(site)
      if keyword.unavailable_usernames.find_by_host_id(@host.id)
        memo[@host.name] = true
      else
        memo[@host.name] = false
      end
    end
  end
  threads.each { |t| t.join }
  memo
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by the autoloader. If the `Host` class is not yet loaded when first entering the loop where you create a couple of new threads, it is autoloaded, i.e. Rails searches the loadpath for a file matching the naming conventions and requires it.

This process is not threadsave. In your case, as you are creating servral threads in quick succession, each trying to autoload the  *global* class, you get race conditions and strange things happen. Basically, you have two options for tackling this:

1. You can explicitly load the model before starting your threads by using `require 'host'` before starting your loop.
2. Or you can set `config.threadsave!` in an initializer. This will (among other things) preload all your classes when starting your server. This is preferred as with this, you avoid a truckload of other difficult to debug concurrency issues. For more information about `config.threadsafe!`, please refer to the [excellent article by Aaron Patterson](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html) arguing it should be removed altogether in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you've quoted above is in a model's .rb file, add `require_relative "host"` to the top of that file.