# Expected model.rb to define MODEL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 tables Collections, Tracks and ProductContributors
Association of them is as follows

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_contributors, :as => :product 
  has_many :tracks, :through => Product_contributors, :as=> :product
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :product_contributors, :as => :product 
 has_many :collections, :through => Product_contributors, :as => :product
end

class ProductContributor < < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :track
end
```

whenever i hit the url for product contributor i get the following error : 
***Expected /app/models/track.rb to define TRACK***
I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330750/loaderror-expected-app-path-models-model-file-rb-to-define-model-name) url but didnt help me in any case. I dont have the autoload issue, all my models are loaded properl

Any help would be highly appreciated..!!

Comment: What is the name of your class defined in track.rb?

Answer (score 0):

I dare say its because of the typo in your `Track` class.

```
has_many :collections, :through => Product_contributors, :as => :product
```

is not valid.  Try:

```
has_many :collections, :through => :product_contributors, :as => :product
```

Basically, it is trying to load the Model, but its finding the typo in the association, and it is then not loading, causing it to seem like the class is not there.  I assume you will have a similar situation with the `Collection` class as well.